# Chartjs Annotation Plugin Click Event

Tags: javascript, events, click

I have been trying to implement this sample code in my own project https://jsfiddle.net/caj89x6L/ and it works great but I can't figure out how to make the created annotations be clickable. I'm very new to events/listeners in javascript. Here is one of the things I have tried so far but I seem to be missing something because the click does not work.

```
  events: ['click'],
   annotation: {
      drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
     annotations: annotations,
     onClick: function(e) {
                console.log("was clicked");
            }
```

I've found lots of examples that have annotations in array brackets [] and can't seem to find anything with using a map like this jsFiddle. I tried reading a bit more and using an event listener but I couldn't get that to work either. Am I missing something fundamental about events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [working JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/59d7qk8L/2/) forked out of the one you've provided.

`onClick` handler should be added to the annotations object and the `'click'` event should be registered in the `annotation` property of the chart options.

Comment: Thank you, Dima Mamchur. I didn't know that it needed to be registered inside the annotation property. I am getting an error `chartjs-plugin-annotation.js:261 Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.` I have read on github that this error has happened to others as well so I will continue to work on fixing it. Thank you